# PropTypes error while Passing array as props

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that is getting array in props like below

> 0: "Euser1@gmail.com"
> 1: "Euser2@yahoo.com"
> length: 2

```
export default function EnableUser({ props }) {
const [emailCount, setEmailCount] = useState(props.length),
// Here I'm getting this error 'length' is missing in props validation eslintreact/prop-types

}
```

I would like to get the array size, I tried length method. But I'm getting the below ESlint Error

> Line 44:46:  'length' is missing in props validation  react/prop-types

I tried with below Proptypes, but not able to solve it.

```
EnableUser.propTypes = {
  props: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string),
}

EnableUser.defaultProps = {
  props: '',
}
```

How can I solve this error
'length' is missing in props validation eslintreact/prop-types

Usage of this component:

```
eusers = ['Euser1@gmail.com', 'Euser2@yahoo.com'] 
<EnableUser props={eusers} />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you show me how do you use the EnableUser component? You need to use a name for the property such as "users" or "data".

Then you will need to code like this

```
props.users.length
```

or

```
props.data.length
```

Comment: Like this const Eusers = ['Euser1@gmail.com', 'Euser2@yahoo.com']
 <EnableUser props={Eusers} />

Comment: You need to pass like this. <EnableUser users={Eusers} />